# Java JDBC SQL Syntax error with PreparedStatement.setTimestamp. Value gets cut off at the colon ':' in time

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

Whenever I try to execute a prepared statement, it throws a `MySQLSyntaxErrorException` with:

> **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO    Information (stamp) VALUES ('2017-01-24 1' at
>   **line 1**

It looks like it's getting cut off at the colon ":' of the time part of the format.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Information (stamp) VALUES (?);"
...
statement.setTimeStamp(1, new Timestamp(system.currentTimeMillis()));
```

I've tried a bunch of different ways of getting a system time stamp and converting it to java.sql.Timestamp, but it continues to throw that same error.

My table has a column stamp of type TIMESTAMP.

Comment: try now() instead of setting the value.  INSERT INTO Information (stamp) VALUES (now());

Comment: Your code looks OK, so please provide more information e.g. more exception stack, more java code

Comment: Well I had shortened it for brevity, but here is some more complete code.
Complete Query:
`String sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (other1, other2, other3)" + " VALUES (?, ?, ?);" + "INSERT INTO Information (date1, stamp)" + " VALUES (?, ?); ";`

I then have a the corresponding setString, setInt, setDate calls. The timestamp is the only one that is having problems. This is all in a try catch block.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ah I found the problem. I didn't realize that prepared statements did not allow multiple queries. My options were to use two statements or add on a connection parameter while sending my connection request

`?allowMultipleQueries=true`. This allows multiple queries separated by a semi-colon. Thanks yall! –

Comment: You should almost never have a reason to use `allowMultipleQueries=true`, and nothing in your original question suggested that this was the problem (the code shown only uses a single query).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yah. My original question was wrong. I should have posted my more complete code. If I don't use allowMultipleQueries, how would I go about executing more than one query in a single method? Must I use multiple statements? I heard it was more efficient to use the same one.